# Proving that extension by radicals implies solvable group

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I'm trying to understand the following excerpt from Fraleigh's *A First Course In Abstract Algebra*, Seventh Edition, pp. 472-473:

> **56.4 Theorem** Let $F$ be a field of characteristic zero, and let $F\subseteq E\subseteq K\subseteq \overline F$, where $E$ is a normal extension of $F$ and $K$ is an extension of $F$ by radicals. Then $G(E/F)$ is a solvable group.
>
> *Proof.* Since $K$ is an extension by radicals, $K = F(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_r)$ where $\alpha_1^{n_1}\in F$ and each $\alpha_i^{n_i}\in F(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_{i-1})$ for $1< i\leq r$. Now form the splitting field $L_1$ of $f_1(x) = x^{n_1} - \alpha_1^{n_1}$ over $F$. Then $L_1$ is a normal extension of $F$, and since $\alpha_1^{n_1}\in F$, the preceding lemma implies that $G(L_1/F)$ is a solvable group. By assumption, $\alpha_2^{n_2}\in F(\alpha_1)\subseteq L_1$, and we form the polynomial
>   $$
>  f_2(x) = \prod_{\sigma\in G(L_1/F)} [x^{n_2} - \sigma(\alpha_2)^{n_2}].
> $$

My question is, why is Fraleigh able to use the expression $\sigma(\alpha_2)^{n_2}$, when we don't necessarily know that $\alpha_2$ is in the domain of $\sigma$, $L_1$? Shouldn't we be using $\alpha_2^{n_2}$, which we know to be in the domain of $\sigma$, so then the definition of $f_2(x)$ would be
$$
 f_2(x) = \prod_{\sigma\in G(L_1/F)} [x^{n_2} - \sigma(\alpha_2^{n_2})]?
$$
I see that if $\sigma(\alpha_2)$ were defined, then by the properties of homomorphisms we would have $\sigma(\alpha_2^{n_2}) = \sigma(\alpha_2)^{n_2}$, but I don't think we know that there is a value for $\sigma(\alpha_2)$. Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

**Abstract**

The alternative definition you suggest for $f_2(x)$ is the correct one. I will support this claim by giving a complete proof of the theorem, following the same procedure as outlined in the book, but including all the major details omitted in the original proof.

---

**Preliminaries**

Let me first introduce some notation. For a subset $A\subseteq\bar{F}$, let $S(A)\subseteq\bar{F}$ be the set of elements generated by the elements of $A$, that is, all elements that can be written as a finite combination of sums, differences, products and quotients of the elements of $A$. It follows that if $A$ contains an element $a\neq 0$, then $S(A)$ is a field: $0 = a-a \in S(A)$, $1 = a/a \in S(A)$, all elements has additive and (except 0) multiplicative inverses, and $S(A)$ is closed under addition and multiplication. The remaining field properties are fulfilled by virtue of $S(A)$ being a subset of the field $\bar{F}$. It is clear that $S(A)$ must be the smallest subfield of $\bar{F}$ containing $A$, so we may for instance use this notation to express simple algebraic extentions $F(\alpha)$ as $S(F\cup\{\alpha\})$.

$S$ satisfies some simple equations; first, it is clear that if $A\subseteq B$, then $S(A)\subseteq S(B)$. It is also true that $S(S(A)) = S(A)$: On one hand, $A\subseteq S(A)$ implies $S(A)\subseteq S(S(A))$. Conversely, suppose $x\in S(S(A))$. Then $x$ can be expressed as a combination of a finite number of elements of $S(A)$ and the four aritmetic types. Each element of $S(A)$ appearing in the expression of $x$ may in turn be written as separate expressions using a finite number of elements of $A$. Then all these expressions can be substituted into the expression of $x$, and the resulting expression shows that $x\in S(A)$.

We now move on to the identity
$$S(S(A)\cup B) = S(A\cup B)$$
which we shall need in the proof. One inclusion follows from the inclusion $A\cup B\subseteq S(A)\cup B$. For the other, observe that $S(A)\subseteq S(A\cup B)$ and $B\subseteq S(B)\subseteq S(A\cup B)$ implies $S(A)\cup B\subseteq S(A\cup B)$, and therefore $S(S(A)\cup B)\subseteq S(S(A\cup B)) = S(A\cup B)$.

Finally, let $Z(f(x))\subseteq\bar{F}$ denote the set of zeroes of any given polynomial $f(x)\in\bar{F}[x]$. Observe that $Z$ satisfies the identity $Z(f(x)g(x)) = Z(f(x))\cup Z(g(x))$. Also note that the splitting field of a polynomial $f(x)\in F[x]$ over $F$ can now be expressed in a concise way as $S(F\cup Z(f(x)))$.

---

**Proof of Theorem 56.4**

First we use that $K$ is an extension by radicals to establish that there exists a subset $\{\alpha_1,...,\alpha_r\}\subseteq\bar{F}$ such that $K = F(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_r)$ where $\alpha_1^{n_1}\in F$ and $\alpha_i^{n_i}\in F(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_{i-1})$ for $1<i\leq r$. Let $K_i$ denote the extension field $F(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_i)$, or equivalently, $S(F\cup\{\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_i\})$.

We will prove the theorem by constructing a sequence of finite normal extensions $L_i$ of $F$ such that $K_i\leq L_i$ and $G(L_i/F)$ is solvable. In particular, the last field in the sequence $L = L_r$ will have a solvable Galois group $G(L/F)$. The subgroup $G(L/E)$ is normal since $L$ is a normal extension of $E$ ($L$ is separable over $E$ by 51.9, and a splitting field over $E$ since it is a splitting field over $F\leq E$). Hence by the Galois theorem 56.3 there is an isomorphism $G(E/F)\simeq G(L/F)/G(L/E)$. But $G(L/F)/G(L/E)$ is solvable by exercise 29 of section 35, and therefore $G(E/F)$ is solvable, which is what we were to prove.

Now to the definition of $L_i$: Let $L_0 = F$, and define the rest recursively by the formula
\begin{equation}
L_i = S(L_{i-1}\cup Z(f_i(x)))
   \quad\text{where}\quad 
f_i(x) = \prod_{\sigma\in G(L_{i-1}/F)}[x^{n_i}-\sigma(\alpha_i^{n_i})]
\end{equation}
We will show that $L_i$ satisfies the following three properties:

1. $K_i\leq L_i$
2. $L_i$ is a finite normal extension of $F$
3. $G(L_i/F)$ is solvable

The first propery implies that $\alpha_i^{n_i}\in L_{i-1}$, which means the definition of $f_i(x)$ makes sense. The other two properties are precisely the ones we needed to deduce that $G(E/F)$ is solvable. Hence we are done after showing these three properties.

1. $L_0 = K_0 = F$ by definition. Assume by induction that $K_{i-1}\leq L_{i-1}$. Then
   $$\begin{eqnarray*}
   K_i &=& S(F\cup\{\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_i\}) = S(S(F\cup\{\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_{i-1}\})\cup\{\alpha_i\}) \\\\
   &=& S(K_{i-1}\cup\{\alpha_i\})\leq S(L_{i-1}\cup\{\alpha_i\})\leq S(L_{i-1}\cup Z(x^{n_i}-\alpha_i^{n_i}))\\
   &\leq& S(L_{i-1}\cup\left(\bigcup_\sigma Z(x^{n_i}-\sigma(\alpha_i^{n_i}))\right)) = S(L_{i-1}\cup Z(\prod_\sigma [x^{n_i}-\sigma(\alpha_i^{n_i})]))\\
   &=& S(L_{i-1}\cup Z(f_i(x))) = L_i
   \end{eqnarray*}$$
2. $L_i$ is a finite extension of $L_{i-1}$, which we as induction hypothesis may assume is a finite extension of $F$. But then $[L_i:F] = [L_i:L_{i-1}][L_{i-1}:F]$ is also finite, so $L_i$ is a finite extension of $F$. $L_i$ is a separable extension of $F$ since $F$ is perfect (Theorem 51.13). Thus it remains only to prove that $L_i$ is a splitting field over $F$. Assume by induction that $L_{i-1}$ is a splitting field over $F$. This means there exists a set of polynomials $g_j(x)\in F[x]$ for $j\in J$ such that
   $$L_{i-1} = S(F\cup\left(\bigcup_{j\in J}Z(g_j(x))\right))$$
   Since
   $$ L_i = S(L_{i-1}\cup Z(f_i(x))) = S(F\cup\left(\bigcup_{j\in J}Z(g_j(x))\right)\cup Z(f_i(x))) $$
   we see that $L_i$ is a splitting field over $F$ if $f_i(x)$ happens to be an element of $F[x]$. We will show that this indeed is the case. Observe first that any ring homomorphism $\phi:R\rightarrow R'$ induces a homomorphism $\bar{\phi}:R[x]\rightarrow R'[x]$ such that $\bar{\phi}(c_0+c_1x+\cdots+c_nx^n) = \phi(c_0)+\phi(c_1)x+\cdots+\phi(c_n)x^n$. Now, since each $\tau\in G(L_{i-1}/F)$ is a ring homomorphism (automorphism) $\tau:L_{i-1}\rightarrow L_{i-1}$, it has an induced homomorphism $\bar{\tau}:L_{i-1}[x]\rightarrow L_{i-1}[x]$. Applied to $f_i(x)$ this yields
   $$ \bar{\tau}(f_i(x)) = \bar{\tau}\left(\prod_\sigma[x^{n_i}-\sigma(\alpha_i^{n_i})]\right) = \prod_\sigma\bar{\tau}(x^{n_i}-\sigma(\alpha_i^{n_i})) = \prod_\sigma(x^{n_i}-\tau\sigma(\alpha_i^{n_i})) $$
   where the last expression is just a rearrangment of the factors in $f_i(x)$, so $\bar{\tau}(f_i(x)) = f_i(x)$. On the other hand, if $c_0+c_1x+\cdots+c_mx^m$ is the expression of $f_i(x)$ after multiplying out all factors, we get
   $$ f_i(x) = \bar{\tau}(f_i(x)) = \bar{\tau}(c_0+c_1x+\cdots+c_mx^m) = \tau(c_0)+\tau(c_1)x+\cdots+\tau(c_m)x^m $$
   which means $\tau(c_k)=c_k$ for all $\tau\in G(L_{i-1}/F)$. The elements of $L_i$ with this property are precisely those contained in $F$: by assumption $L_{i-1}$ is a normal extension of $F$, so $(L_{i-1})_{G(L_{i-1}/F)} = F$ by the Galois theorem. Hence $c_k\in F$ for all $k$ and consequently $f_i(x)\in F[x]$.
3. We shall construct a tower of fields $L_{i-1} = M_0\leq M_1\leq\cdots\leq M_m = L_i$ such that all $M_j$ are normal extensions of $M_0$, and such that the Galois groups $G(M_{j+1}/M_j)$ are solvable. The series
   $$ \{e\} = G(M_m/M_m)\leq G(M_m/M_{m-1})\leq\cdots\leq G(M_m/M_0) = G(L_i/L_{i-1})\leq G(L_i/F) $$
   is then subnormal (in the non-strict inequality sense): Note first that since all
   fields $M_j$ are normal over a common field $M_0$, each $M_j$ must be normal over all subfields $M_k$ in the tower. In particular we have that both $M_m$ and $M_{j+1}$ are normal extensions of $M_j$. But then it follows from the Galois theorem that $G(M_m/M_{j+1})$ is a normal subgroup of $G(M_m/M_j)$. Also, since both $L_i$ and $L_{i-1}$ are normal extensions of $F$ (property 2), we can use the Galois theorem to conclude that $G(L_i/L_{i-1})$ is a normal subgroup of $G(L_i/F)$. Next, by construction, each quotient group
   $$G(M_m/M_j)/G(M_m/M_{j+1})\simeq G(M_{j+1}/M_j)$$
   is solvable. The last quotient group $G(L_i/F)/G(L_i/L_{i-1})\simeq G(L_{i-1}/F)$ is also solvable, if we assume by induction that $G(L_{i-1}/F)$ is solvable. Thus, since each consequtive pair of groups has a solvable quotient group, we may by excercise 7 insert simple abelian refinements between each pair. The resulting series (after deleting any repeated entries) is the desired solution of $G(L_i/F)$.
   We now proceed to define $M_j$: Let
   $$ M_j = S(M_{j-1}\cup Z(x^{n_i}-\sigma_j(\alpha_i^{n_i}))) $$
   where $\{\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_m\} = G(L_{i-1}/F)$ is an enumeration of the elements of $G(L_{i-1}/F)$. We immediately see that $M_j$ is the splitting field of $x^{n_i}-\sigma_j(\alpha_i^{n_i})$ over $M_{j-1}$, and since this is exactly the kind of extension discussed in the preceding lemma 56.3, it follows that $G(M_j/M_{j-1})$ is solvable. Thus what remains to be shown is that each $M_j$ is a normal extension of $M_0$ and that $M_m = L_i$. Showing that $M_j$ is a normal extension of $M_0$ amounts to showing that $M_j$ is a splitting field over $M_0$. By expanding the recursive definition of $M_j$, and using the identity $S(S(A)\cup B) = S(A\cup B)$ repeatedly, we find that
   $$ M_j = S(M_0\cup\bigcup_{k=1}^j Z(x^{n_i}-\sigma_k(\alpha_i^{n_i}))) $$
   This shows that $M_j$ is the splitting field of $\{x^{n_i}-\sigma_1(\alpha_i^{n_i}),\dots,x^{n_i}-\sigma_j(\alpha_i^{n_i})\}$ over $M_0$. For $j=m$ we have that
   $$ M_m = S(M_0\cup\bigcup_{k=1}^m Z(x^{n_i}-\sigma_k(\alpha_i^{n_i}))) = S(M_0\cup Z(\prod_{k=1}^m[x^{n_i}-\sigma_k(\alpha_i^{n_i})])) = S(L_{i-1}\cup Z(f_i(x))) $$
   so $M_m = L_i$, completing the proof.

---

**Appendix**

Here I will solve the two exercises that were referenced in the proof. To simplify the proofs that the exercises ask for, let me start by introducing a correspondence theorem which does not appear in the book:

**Theorem:**  Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of a group $G$, and let $\gamma: G\rightarrow G/N$ be the canonical homomorphism. Then the map $H\mapsto\gamma[H]$ is a bijective correspondence between the subgroups of $G$ containing $N$ and the subgroups of $G/H$.

*Proof:* Recall that $G/N$ is constructed by creating a partition of the elements of $G$, letting the elements of $G/N$ be the various bins in this partition. The bins in $G/N$ are the subsets of the form $xN = \{xn\,|\,n\in N\}$ for $x\in G$. The group operation on these bins is defined thus: $(xN)(yN) = (xy)N$. A subgroup of $G/N$ is a subcollection of these bins having the property of being closed under group operation and element inversion. Let $H'$ be any subgroup of $G/N$, and let $H\subseteq G$ be the union of all the elements in each bin of $H'$. If $x,y\in H$ then $xN,yN\in H'$, so $(xy)N\in H'$, but then $xy\in H$. Similarly $x\in H\Rightarrow xN\in H'$ $\Rightarrow x^{-1}N\in H'\Rightarrow x^{-1}\in H$. This shows that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. Note also that $H$ contains $eN = N$ and satisfies $\gamma[H] = H'$, hence the correspondence is surjective. To see injectivity we will begin in the opposite end and start with an arbitrary subgroup $H\leq G$ containing $N$. Since $N$ is necessarily a normal subgroup of $H$, we can partition $H$ into a group of bins $H/N$. The bins in this group are of the form $xN$ for $x\in H$, which evidently form a subset of the bins in $G/N$. Hence $H/N$ is a subgroup of $G/N$. Note now that we can recover the mapped subgroup $H$ from the image $\gamma[H] = H/N$ by taking the union of all elements of each bin in $H/N$ (just observe that $xN\subseteq H$ for each bin $xN\in H/N$). This implies injectivity, and the correspondence is proven.
$$\tag*{$\Box$}$$

If $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $H$ is a subgroup containing $N$, we saw in the proof of the above correspondence theorem that $H/N$ is a subgroup of $G/N$, and that its corresponding subgroup in $G$ is $H$. We will therefore in what follows write the corresponding subgroup of $H$ as $H/N$.

The first exercise I'm going to solve is not literally the one given in the book, but rather the natural lemma from which the result in the book will follow:

$$ $$
**Exercise 56.7**    Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. If $G/N$ is solvable, then there exists a refinement $N=H_0<H_1<\cdots<H_n=G$ such that $H_{i+1}/H_i$ are simple abelian for $0\leq i<n$.

*Proof:* All subgroups of $G/N$ are of the form $H/N$ where $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ containing $N$. A solution of $G/N$ may thus be written
$$ N/N=H_0/N<H_1/N<\cdots <H_n/N=G/N $$
We shall show that the series
$$ N=H_0<H_1<\cdots <H_n=G $$
is a simple abelian refinement of $N<G$. Observe first that $H_i$ is a normal subgroup of $H_{i+1}$ since $H_i/N$ is a normal subgroup of $H_{i+1}/N$; this follows by lemma 34.3, which in plain text states that the subgroup correspondence theorem we proved above maps normal subgroups to normal subgroups. But then $H_{i+1}/H_i$ is simple abelian by the third isomorphism theorem 34.7:
$$ H_{i+1}/H_i\simeq (H_{i+1}/N)/(H_i/N) $$
hence $N=H_0<H_1<\cdots <H_n=G$ is a refinement with the desired propery.
$$\tag*{$\Box$}$$
$$ $$

**Exercise 35.29**    Prove that a homomorphic image of a solvable group is solvable.

*Proof:* Let $G$ be a solvable group. The homomorphic image of $G$ is isomorphic to $G/N$ where $N$ is the kernel of the homomorphism (1st isomorphism theorem), so we shall prove that $G/N$ is solvable for normal subgroups $N\leq G$. If $N=\{e\}$ or $N=G$ the group $G/N$ is obviously solvable, so suppose $\{e\}<N<G$. By theorem 35.16, this series can be refined to a composition series $\{e\}=H_0<\cdots <H_n=G$, and by the comment following definition 35.18 the factor groups $H_{i+1}/H_i$ must be abelian. Let $H_k = N$. Then $H_i/N$ are subgroups of $G/N$ for $k\leq i\leq n$, which means we have a series
$$ N/N=H_k/N<H_{k+1}/N<\cdots <H_n/N=G/N $$
This is subnormal by the fact that $H_i$ is a normal subgroup of $H_{i+1}$, since this implies $H_i/N$ is a normal subgroup of $H_{i+1}/N$, by lemma 34.3. But then it follows from the third isomorphism theorem that $(H_{i+1}/N)/(H_i/N)\simeq H_{i+1}/H_i$, which means $(H_{i+1}/N)/(H_i/N)$ is simple abelian, hence the above series is a solution of $G/N$.
$$\tag*{$\Box$}$$